# Select text strings with multiple formatting tags within

Tags: regex, vb.net, xpath, html-agility-pack

**Context**:

VB.NET application using htmlagility pack to handle html document.

**Issue**:

In a html document, I'd like to prefixe all the strings starting with # and ending with space by an url whatever formatting tags are used within.
So #sth would became *http://www.anything.tld/sth*

For instance:

Before:

```
<p>#string1</p> blablabla
<p><strong>#stri</strong>ng2</p> bliblibli
```

After:

```
<p><a href="http://www.anything.tld/string1">#string1</a> blablabla</p>
<p><a href="http://www.anything.tld/string2"><strong>#stri</strong>ng2</a> bliblibli</p>
```

I guess i can achieve this with html agility pack but how to select the entire text string without its formatting ?

Or should i use a simple regex replace routine?

Comment: I don't get why my question was down voted without any kind of comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution. I'm sure it would make some experienced developpers bleed from every hole but it actually works.
The htmlcode is in strCorpusHtmlContent

```
Dim matchsHashtag As MatchCollection
Dim matchHashtag As Match
Dim captureHashtag As Capture
Dim strHashtagFormatted As String
Dim strRegexPatternHashtag As String = "#([\s]*)(\w*)"
matchsHashtag = Regex.Matches(strCorpusHtmlContent, strRegexPatternHashtag)
For Each matchHashtag In matchsHashtag
     For Each captureHashtag In matchHashtag.Captures
         Dim strHashtagToFormat As String
         Dim strHashtagValueToFormat As String
         ' Test if the hashtag is followed by a tag
         If Mid(strCorpusHtmlContent, captureHashtag.Index + captureHashtag.Length + 1, 1) = "<" Then
            strHashtagValueToFormat = captureHashtag.Value                    
            Dim intStartPosition As Integer = captureHashtag.Index + captureHashtag.Length + 1
            Dim intSpaceCharPostion As Integer = intStartPosition
            Dim nextChar As Char
            Dim blnInATag As Boolean = True
            Do Until (nextChar = " " Or nextChar = vbCr Or nextChar = vbLf Or nextChar = vbCrLf) And blnInATag = False
                  nextChar = CChar(Mid(strCorpusHtmlContent, intSpaceCharPostion + 1, 1))
                  If nextChar = "<" Then
                     blnInATag = True
                  ElseIf nextChar = ">" Then
                     blnInATag = False
                  End If
                  If blnInATag = False And nextChar <> ">" And nextChar <> " " Then
                     strHashtagValueToFormat &= nextChar
                  End If
                  intSpaceCharPostion += 1
              Loop
              strHashtagToFormat = Mid(strCorpusHtmlContent, captureHashtag.Index + 1, intSpaceCharPostion - captureHashtag.Length)
         Else
              strHashtagToFormat = captureHashtag.Value
         End If

             strHashtagFormatted = "<a href=" & Chr(34) & strUrnPrefixHashtag & strHashtagValueToFormat & Chr(34) & ">" & strHashtagToFormat & "</a>"

             strCorpusHtmlContent = Regex.Replace(strCorpusHtmlContent, strHashtagToFormat, strHashtagFormatted)
     Next
Next
```

Before:

```
<p>#has<strong>hta</strong><em>g_m</em>u<span style="text-decoration: underline;">ltifortmat</span> to convert</p>
```

After:

```
<p><a href="web:keyword:#hashtag_multi ">#has<strong>hta</strong><em>g_m</em>u<span style="text-decoration: underline;">ltiformat</span></a> to convert</p>
```